# Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

In my React project I am getting the following error for my `App` component.

```
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<ClassAttributes<App> & RouteChildrenProps<{}, unknown> & { userData: UserDataType | undefined; userRightList: UserRightListType[] | undefined; userPermissionList: string[] | undefined; } & { ...; }, "ref" | ... 3 more ... | "key">': history, location, matchts(2739)
```

Following is my index.tsx file code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import reduxStore from './redux/store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={reduxStore.store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App /> // getting the error here
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

and following is my App.tsx file code:

```
import { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import ErrorBoundary from './components/ErrorBoundary';
import { getUserByToken, getUserRights, setUserRights } from './redux/actions';
import { ReduxStateType } from './type-definitions';
import { isAuthenticated } from './utils/is-authenticated';

type StoreProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
type DispatchProps = typeof mapDispatch;

type PropsType = RouteComponentProps & StoreProps & DispatchProps;

class App extends Component<PropsType, any> {
  componentDidMount() {
    const {
      userData,
      getUserByToken,
      getUserRights,
      userRightList,
    } = this.props;
    const isAuth = isAuthenticated(userData);
    if (!userData?.username && isAuth) {
      getUserByToken();
    }
    if (userRightList?.length === 0 && isAuth) {
      getUserRights();
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps: PropsType) {
    const {
      userData,
      userRightList,
      userPermissionList,
      setUserRights,
    } = this.props;

    if (
      userData &&
      Object.keys(userData).length > 0 &&
      userRightList &&
      userRightList?.length > 0 &&
      userPermissionList?.length === 0
    ) {
      setUserRights();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <ErrorBoundary></ErrorBoundary>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: ReduxStateType) {
  return {
    userData: state.auth?.userData,
    userRightList: state.auth?.userRightList,
    userPermissionList: state.shared?.userPermissionList,
  };
}

const mapDispatch = {
  getUserByToken,
  getUserRights,
  setUserRights,
};

export default connect<StoreProps, DispatchProps>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatch
)(App);
```

I am getting the error in `index.tsx` file in the `render` method. I am new to TypeScript. I would appreciate it very much if someone can tell me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: I'm assuming it `PropType` that's causing the issue. As for what specifically, I dk since I long ago forgot how to use Typescript with the old version of React.

Comment: Okay, but I am not missing any type definitions. The component does not have `ownProps`. There is only `RouteComponentProps` and `Redux` Props

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two different packages which might be injecting their own props into your component: Redux and React Router.

When you define your component as `class App extends Component<PropsType, any>`, it expects to receive `PropsType` as its props.

```
type PropsType = RouteComponentProps & StoreProps & DispatchProps;
```

It needs to receive all three of the interfaces that you've listed as props.  `StoreProps` and `DispatchProps` are the ones which are injected by the Redux `connect` higher-order component, and these ones are fine.  Your error message tells you that the missing props are `history`, `location`, and `match`.  These are the properties of `RouteComponentProps`.

Right now your component doesn't actually use any of the Router props, so the simplest solution is just to remove `RouteComponentProps` from `PropsType`.  By putting it there, you are requiring that those props be present.

If you want to actually include the `RouteComponentProps`, then changes need to be made in `index.tsx`.  You have wrapped your `App` in a `BrowserRouter`, but it's not actually doing anything because you haven't defined any routes.  You need a `Switch` component with `Route` components inside of it.  If `App` is loaded within a `Route` component, then the `RouteComponentProps` will be injected.

Check out the [React Router docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) for how to set up multiple routes.  This will load `App` always (so no change), but now it will get the required props.  There are multiple ways to declare the component for a Route, but you want to use the [component prop](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component) or [render prop](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func) instead of children because these allow typescript to know that the router props are included.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={reduxStore.store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/"
          component={App}
        />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```